# How to sort column according to name, ascending and descnding

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I am in desperate need help on using jQuery and tablesorter plugin from http://tablesorter.com/.

What I want to do is when I click a button in my html, a new window pops up and using ajax, I display the data in the window from the database, using PHP as well.

So far I've been using raw javascript codes so now I've come to a stop as I have to sort a column according to alphabetical ascending and descending order. So my questions are:

1. Where do I start? I have downloaded the files required (jqeury.tablesorter.js and jquery-2.1.4.min.js) and I have included it in the html file that I used for my pop up window. (I am doing my javascript codes on an external file called function.js)

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
   ```
2. If I just want to sort one column, which consists of names, according to ascending alphabetical order or vice versa WHEN I CLICK THE HEADER, is there an easier way to do it? (This question is assuming if I do not use the tablesort plugin)

Note: Please do treat me as a super beginner as I only know the basics of jQuery.

In my PHP file:

```
                               .
                               .
                          Some Codes
                               .
                               .

if($num_row)
    {
        $count = 0;

        echo "<table id='table2' class='table2' border=1>"; 

        //Table headers
        echo "<tr><th>ID</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Badge Number</th>";
        echo "<th>Category</th>";
        echo "<th>Action</th>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $badge_number = $row['badge_number'];
            $category = $row['category'];
            $privilege = $row['privilege'];
            $count++;

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td id=\"row$count\">$id</td>";
            echo "<td>$name</td>"; 
            echo "<td>$badge_number</td>";
            echo "<td>$category</td>";
            echo "<td><input type=\"button\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\" onclick=\"deleteThis($count, $privilege)\"/></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }
        echo "</table>";
                             .
                             .
                          Other codes
                             .
                             .
```

The html file that I use for the pop up window aka viewTable.html:

```
<html>
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
     <script language="javascript" src="function.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
 </head>

 <body>
      <script>displayTable();</script>
      <div id="divTable"></div>
 <body>
</html>
```

This is one of the javascript functions in my external javascript file, function.js, using ajax just to show currently how I display the table and my current knowledge:

```
function displayTable()
{
window.onload = function()
{
    var page = "database.php"
    var parameters = 'action=update';
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if(xmlhttp==null)
    {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return false;
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {      
       document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       sorrtable.makeSortable(sortThis);
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", page+"?"+parameters, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    } 
}//displayTable()
```

Comment: Why don't you return sorted result from php itself? Try that.

Comment: But I want the original result first as it's based on an ID, so that's why I returned the normal result. Now I want the user to be able to click on the header so it will sort the names.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the php part, but here is the client-side coding needed; the ajax request is set up to make it work in jsFiddle so to change it for your site, remove the ajax `method`, `data` and change the `url` to point to the php page ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/fg85fzqj/))

```
$(function () {

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 650,
    modal: true
  });

  $("#open").on("click", function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    var page = 1,
      parameters = 'action=update';
    displayTable(page, parameters);
  });

  var initTable = function(data) {
    var $table = $('#dialog table');
    $table.find('tbody').append(data);
    if ($table[0].config) {
      // tablesorter already initialized; now update the data
      $table.trigger('update');
    } else {
      $table.tablesorter({
        debug: true,
        theme: 'blue',
        widthFixed: true,
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'columns']
      });
    }
  },
  displayTable = function (page, parameters) {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'html',
      url: 'database.php?get=' + page + '&' + parameters
    }).done(function (data) {
      initTable(data);
    });
  };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with tablesorter: sortlist.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#tablesorter-demo").tablesorter({ theme: 'blue', 
                                            widgets: ['saveSort','zebra','resizable','filter'],
                                            initialized: function (table) {
                                            //$.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['', ''  ], true);
                                        $.tablesorter.setFilters( table, ['', '', '!= USA'  ], true);
    }

                                            });//, widgets: ['zebra']}); //sortList:[[0,0],[2,1]],
        // initialized abc  http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/785/
        //http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html



        //$("#options").tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0]], headers: { 3:{sorter: false}, 4:{sorter: false}}});

        //hier staat de input boxes example: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-grouping.html 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: This, I do not understand at all. First of all where did you get #tablesorter-demo from or rather, where would/should it be? I need some kind of explanation to be able to understand.