# Tablesorter filter not showing in JQuery Dialog box on change event

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using Tablesorter filter in JQuery dialog box. When I open the dialog box for the first time, the Tablesorter filter loading and working properly. The dialog box contain a Drop down list, when I am selecting value from this Drop down list, the dialog box re-loading and displaying data BUT the Tablesorter filter does not appear/visible.

Can anybody help me solve this issue.

Thanks

```
var $dialogproperties = $('#dialogs');

$(document).on('change', '#ddl_Com', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = getURL;
        var data1 = getValues();

        url = '@Url.Action("Com_submit")?ID=' + id;

        $.post(url, data1, function (data) {
            //// Open popup dialog box
            var tmp = data.commentdisplay.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
            $dialogproperties.html('');
            $dialogproperties.dialog({ title: $('#title').text() });
            $dialogproperties.html(tmp);
            $dialogproperties.dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
});

$(function () {
        //// - Dialog box width and height
        var wWidth = $(window).width();
        var dWidth = wWidth * 0.9;
        var wHeight = $(window).height();
        var dHeight = wHeight * 0.9;
        var dialog = "";
        dialog = $("#dialogs").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: dWidth,
            height: dHeight,
            fluid: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                stopscroll();
                alert('t');

                var $table = $('#tblCom');
                $table.tablesorter({
                    textExtraction: {
                        '.img': function (node) {
                            var $node = $(node);
                            return $node.find('span[title]').attr('title');
                        }
                    },
                    imgAttr: 'title',
                    ignoreCase: false,
                    widthFixed: true,
                    widgets: ["filter", "columnSelector"],
                    widgetOptions: {
                        filter_useParsedData: true,
                        filter_columnFilters: true,
                        filter_ignoreCase: true,
                        filter_defaultAttrib: 'data-value',
                        columnSelector_mediaquery: false
                    }
                });

            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: Please share the code you are using.

Comment: @Mottie, I have added the code above

Comment: I had to update the answer, but I think [it is related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30358176/145346) - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/fg85fzqj/). Essentially, the second time you open the dialog, tablesorter has already been initialized, so update the content or skip initialization.

Comment: @Mottie, how can I skip the initialization, I am getting everything dynamically, so I think to skip initialization will be better, thanks

Comment: I can't tell, is the table completely replaced each time the dialog opens? Or are you only updating the contents? If it is the later method, then the code from the answer will work for you. Actually, it should work for you in either case.

Comment: @Mottie, table completely replaced each time when dialog opens. I checked the answer you provided but don't figure out how it will fit with my purpose.

Comment: Add a `debug:true` option to tablesorter and tell me what you see the second time you open the dialog.

Comment: @Mottie, the error is - {Stopping initialization! No table, thead or tbody      jquery.tablesorter.js:222}. after this there are few other lines of error code as well.

Comment: That sounds like the table doesn't include a `thead`, `tbody` or maybe you need to initialize tablesorter inside of a `setTimeout` to ensure that the dialog has rendered the HTML before initializing the plugin.

Comment: @Mottie, please give me an example

Comment: @Mottie, I have changed the open method {setTimeout(function () {

             $dialogproperties.dialog("open");

         }, 100);} but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code to make sure that the HTML has rendered inside the dialog before initializing tablesorter

```
dialog = $("#dialogs").dialog({
  // ...
  open: function (event, ui) {
    stopscroll();
    setTimeout(function() {
      var $table = $('#tblCom');
      $table.tablesorter({
        // ...
      });
    }, 0);
  },
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Silly question... is there a table with the same ID in the dialog? Make sure the "C" is capitalized in "tblCom".

Comment: Yes, I have exactly the same table name

Comment: And it has both a `<thead>` and `<tbody>`?

Comment: Yes, is has both

Comment: Then you'll need to do more troubleshooting... I don't know why you'd be seeing a `Stopping initialization! No table, thead or tbody` message. Add a `console.log` to check the `$table` variable and double check the HTML.

Comment: I think this is related with JQuery dialog. When dialog box opening the second time, Tablesorter disappearing. There is no way when tablesorter opened first time into the dialog, it will stay as it is until dialog box will be closed.

Comment: Just I have changed html coding and added timeout option, and its worked, thanks for your help